# How do you add a subtitle to multiple XY line chart in c3js.org?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, c3.js

How do you add a subtitle to multi-line chart in c3js.org?  I have a long title and I need to either add a subtitle or wrapping or break the title.

[image: long title in c3.js]

I tried passing in a subtitle like this:

```
                title: {
                  text: title
                },
                subtitle: {
                  text: subtitle
                },
```

However, it does not show up in the chart.

Answer (score 1):

```
//HTML
<div id="chart"></div>

//JS
  var chart = c3.generate({
        data: {

            columns: [
                ['dataName1', 20],
                ['dataName2', 100],
            ],
            onclick: function (d, i) { console.log("onclick", d, i); },
            type:'donut'
        },
        donut:{
            title:'Title'
        }
    });

    d3.select("svg").append("text")
        .attr("x", 420)
        .attr("y", 170)
        .style("text-anchor", "middle")
        .text("SubTitle");
```

Comment: I believe that is the titles of the data feeds, not the title of the chart itself.  I am wondering if the best way to do this is just in the HTML, but then why have a title attribute?

Comment: @calycolor yes data feeds acceptable; but its even useful for subtitles. check it->  https://jsfiddle.net/bwu70xgq/393/

Comment: I added an image to show what I meant by subtitle...subtitle for the chart, not the data.

Comment: @calycolor ur right. i edited check this pls -> https://jsfiddle.net/bwu70xgq/428/

Comment: unfortunately, that is not responsive...it goes away for different screen sizes.